# Mouse double click on QwtScaleDraw

Tags: qt, qwt

I have overridden the `QwtScaleDraw` function to change the Axis properties of the Qwt graph plot.

`class CustomScaleDraw : public QwtScaleDraw`

and by using draw(), drawBackBone(),etc, I am changing the axis properties.
My requirement is to popup a dialog to change the properties of the Axis when the user double clicks on the axis of the graph.

As `QWtScaleDraw` is not inherited with `QObject`, neither mouseDoubleClick nor eventFilter function is able to capture the mouse double click on the Axis. How can I do that?

Comment: Here you have a good [example](https://github.com/GoldenCheetah/GoldenCheetah/tree/931ce07e9976237117ddfddf7aa4d5e33ed91024/qwt/examples/event_filter). The idea is to install the event filter in your `QwtScaleWidget`

Comment: thanks Tarod. im looking into the example now.